# How to change CLion run/debug configuration working directory from CMake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, clion, cmake-language

In my project, with CMake 3.8 for MSVC, in order to change the working directory when debugging MY_TARGET I can put the following:

```
set_property(TARGET ${MY_TARGET} PROPERTY VS_DEBUGGER_WORKING_DIRECTORY "$(SolutionDir)")
```

In CLion, I get the same effect if I manually change the run/debug configuration working directory to `$CMakeCurrentGenerationDir$`.

But is there a way to tell CMake to automatically put `$CMakeCurrentGenerationDir$` in the run/debug configuration working directory?